# Web (weird)wrapped text to plain text string

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert some wrapped text to a plane text string with endlines and all.
The wrapping is however of some wierd kind I have never seen before.
The text is gained from an xml file CDATA section

```
<font color="#bfffffff" size="12"></font><font color="#ff00ff00" size="12">My fellow Muppets,<br><br>We are sorry to say that Devilish Intetions are not going to work out with The Muppet Brigade sorry guys you are just not active ebough I would how ever like to extend an arm to any players that would like to leave and join DynaCorp. If any of you are intrested just drop me a mail and best of luck in your future endevors. <br><br>o7 <br><br><br/></br></br></br></br></br></br></font><font color="#ff007fff" size="14">John Milbroc<br/></font><font color="#bfffffff" size="14">--------------------------<br/></font><font color="#ff007fff" size="14">The Muppet Brigade CEO</font>
```

I've tryed the following tough:

```
z = BeautifulSoup(string)
z.get_text()
```

However BeautifulSoup does not seem to be doing anything.
I'm rather new to python so sorry if this is a realy easy problem.

I think maybe my BeatifulSoup module is broken because when I do this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc ="""
Hi.<br><br>This is a message.<br><br>
"""
print(html_doc)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

print(soup.text)
```

It prints:

```
Hi.<br><br>This is a message.<br><br>

None
```

After trying that I messed around with other stuff and found that if you do

```
soup.get_text()
```

instead of

```
soup.txt
```

It wil print the parsed text.
Very wierd but it worked.
Thanks for te encouragement and keeping me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to parse the html using `BeautifulSoup`? For example:

```
html_doc = """
 ## you copy here your html text  
 """"
```

Then you parse it :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

You extract the text :

```
print soup.text


My fellow Muppets,We are sorry to say that Devilish Intetions are not 
going to work out with The Muppet Brigade sorry guys you are just not active ebough 
I would how ever like to extend an arm to any players that would like to leave and join DynaCorp. 
If any of you are intrested just drop me a mail and best of luck in your future endevors. 
o7 
John Milbroc--------------------------

The Muppet Brigade CEO
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br>, <br/> and </br>` tags in the text, and the wrapping should go away.  Those are line breaks in HTML.